# Jmeter: I can't get the response that I needed for assertion

Tags: jmeter, frame

I have been working on this project and I can't get the response that I needed for assertion because the response body in Jmeter only says "Your browser does not support framing. Please update your browser", but Im using the latest version of Firefox (image 2). I also manually execute the request in the real browser, same as what browser Im using in Jmeter, and didn't encounter the said message. Can someone please tell me whats going on? Thank you for your help
[Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEnwJ.png)

[HTTP header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyjXd.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Most probably the value you're looking for lives inside an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) is being loaded using some [JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) which is not being kicked off by JMeter as it doesn't evaluate JavaScript.

So you need to invoke the relevant request manually using another [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which would load the required page. You can figure out the necessary request URL by looking into page source using your favorite browser [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or by recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

Also be aware that due to asynchronous nature of JavaScript calls it is better to wrap it (and other JavaScript calls, if any, in [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

You can install Parallel Controller and Sampler via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]